# Set time intervals on images with Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, random, time, setinterval

I'm trying to set a time interval using Javascript for an image already randomly picked on page load with PHP. Obviously I can't set a time interval using PHP. So the image is randomly picked using PHP but then once it's randomly picked and the page is loaded, I would like Javascript to take over and generate a new randomly picked one at time intervals of 20 seconds.

I probably could just scrap the whole PHP idea and use Javascript entirely but I'm now intrigued to see if I can get this to work.

Below is my PHP code:

```
    <?php

 $img_rand = array(
  1 => array(
     'url' => 'www.tautic.com/', 
    'img' => '1.jpg', 
    'wth' => '472',        
    'hgt' => '100',      
  'ttl' => 'Tautic',    
    'alt' => 'Tautic'  
   ),                              
   2 => array(
     'url' => 'www.designspark.com/', 
    'img' => '2.jpg', 
    'wth' => '472',        
    'hgt' => '100',        
  'ttl' => 'Design Spark',    
    'alt' => 'Design Spark'  
  ),
  3 => array(
     'url' => 'www.involutionstudios.net/',
    'img' => '3.jpg',
    'wth' => '472',        
    'hgt' => '100',        
  'ttl' => 'Involution Studios - Web Design',   
    'alt' => 'Involution Studios - Web Design'  
   ),
    4 => array(
     'url' => 'www.explorestem.co.uk/', 
    'img' => '4.jpg', 
    'wth' => '472',     
    'hgt' => '100',        
  'ttl' => 'Explore Stem',    
    'alt' => 'Explore Stem' 

   ),
   ); 

   $img = array_rand($img_rand); 
   echo('      
   <div class="random-img">    
   <a href="http://'.$img_rand[$img]['url'].'" title="'.$img_rand[$img]['ttl'].'"                  
   target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/'.$img_rand[$img]['img'].'" width="'.$img_rand[$img]['wth'].'"          
   height="'.$img_rand[$img]['hgt'].'" alt="'.$img_rand[$img]['alt'].'" /> 
  </a>
  </div>
  ');

   ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with having your array in PHP is that only PHP can access it, i.e. JavaScript doesn't know what url's to load. So if you're intent on keeping the php, go with option 1 below, otherwise scrap the php and go with option 2:

### Option 1

You'll have to use ajax on main view, and keep the php seperate. On the php page, instead of outputting the image, output the image info as a JSON object, e.g.

```
$img = array_rand($img_rand);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($img);
```

and then on the page where you're displaying everything, use javascript (I'm using jQuery since it makes ajax way easier) to load the image:

```
<div class="random-img"></div>
<script type="text/javascript>
imgLoop = function() {
    $.get('randomimage.php', function(img) {
        var el = '<a href="http://'+img.url+'" title="'+img.ttl+'" target="_blank">';
        el += '<img src="sponsorimg/'+img.img+'" width="'+img.wth+'" height="'+img.hgt+'" alt="'+img.alt+'" /></a>';
        $('.random-img').empty().append(el);
    });
};
setInterval(imgLoop, 20000);
</script>
```

### Option 2 (better imo)

Unless you're trying to prevent your use from seeing the array of images if they try to view your source, the ajax/php is completely unnecessary in option 1. You could completely scrap the php and just store your images as an array of objects, e.g.

```
images = [
    {
        'url': 'www.tautic.com/', 
        'img': '1.jpg', 
        'wth': '472',        
        'hgt': '100',      
        'ttl': 'Tautic',    
        'alt': 'Tautic'
    },
    {
        'url': 'www.designspark.com/', 
        'img': '2.jpg', 
        'wth':'472',        
        'hgt':'100',        
        'ttl':'Design Spark',    
        'alt':'Design Spark'
    }
    //And so on..
];
```

And then for the interval, just use:

```
<div class="random-img"></div>
<script type="text/javascript>
imgLoop = function() {
    var img = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    var el = '<a href="http://'+img.url+'" title="'+img.ttl+'" target="_blank">';
    el += '<img src="sponsorimg/'+img.img+'" width="'+img.wth+'" height="'+img.hgt+'" alt="'+img.alt+'" /></a>';
    $('.random-img').empty().append(el);
};
setInterval(imgLoop, 20000);
</script>
```

Let me know if this makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, I will go with option 2 :) I understand the second snippet of code in option 2, but the top snippet (the array of images) Where am I putting that? Thanks :)

Comment: The top part can basically go anywhere inside a `<script>` tag. Let me know if it works.. :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, I can't post what I've done here as too long. Does this site have private messaging? I've also tried the Ajax idea with no results :( No images are appearing but also no errors either.

Comment: Is there anyway you could help me out by doing a jsFiddle? Or give me an email liam@invoweb .net, I'm pretty sure your answer will work, there is just something not quite right. Thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot a colon after 'img' in the design spark object. Fixed it and created a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/CnzWV/)  (using an interval of 3000 instead of 20000 so that the functionality is visible).. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to do that :) All seems great, how hard would it be to do a fade effect between image changes? Cheers.

Comment: Great! ... Thanks. I will implement it into the site now and mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete javascript solution, then you will have to keep the array on client.

Keep the dynamic fields blank in HTML / PHP file and load them from javascript.

```
<div class="random-img">
    <a target='_blank' title='' href='' >
        <img id='imageToLoad' src='' height='' width='' alt='' />
    </a>
</div>
```

I have added JQuery for event binding but that can be changed to plain javascript if required.

Here image's load event is monitored. Next random image is loaded after 20 seconds timeout from load or error event. Using `setTimeout` has advantage over `setInterval` as the timeout will be called only after loading of previous image.

`loadImage` function is called explicitly once to load the image for the first time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imageToLoad').on('load', function(e){
       var imageElem = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadImage(imageElem);
        }, 20 * 1000);
    }).on('error',function(e){
       var imageElem = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadImage(imageElem);
        }, 20 * 1000);
    });

    function loadImage(imageElem){
        imageElem = imageElem || $('#imageToLoad').get(0);
        var rndImage = imageArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length)];
        imageElem.src = rndImage.img;
        imageElem.height = rndImage.hgt;
        imageElem.width = rndImage.wth;
        imageElem.alt = rndImage.alt;
        imageElem.parentNode.href = rndImage.url;
        imageElem.parentNode.title = rndImage.ttl;
    }

    var imageArr = [{
        'url' : 'www.tautic.com/', 
        'img' : '1.jpg', 
        'wth' : '472',        
        'hgt' : '100',      
        'ttl' : 'Tautic',    
        'alt' : 'Tautic'
    },{
        'url' : 'www.designspark.com/', 
        'img' : '2.jpg', 
        'wth' : '472',        
        'hgt' : '100',        
        'ttl' : 'Design Spark',    
        'alt' : 'Design Spark'
    },{
        'url' : 'www.involutionstudios.net/',
        'img' : '3.jpg',
        'wth' : '472',        
        'hgt' : '100',        
        'ttl' : 'Involution Studios - Web Design',   
        'alt' : 'Involution Studios - Web Design'
    },{
        'url' : 'www.explorestem.co.uk/', 
        'img' : '4.jpg', 
        'wth' : '472',     
        'hgt' : '100',        
        'ttl' : 'Explore Stem',    
        'alt' : 'Explore Stem'
    }];

    loadImage();
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YtDYk/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. This is clashing with some other .js I have, I can't work out why though. http://involutionstudios.net/earthrover/js/social.js ... Your script is also changing the image on the social tab after the 20 seconds. Hmmm. Thanks

Comment: You can use `$('#imageToLoad').on('load'...` instead of `$('img').on('load'...` so it will bind on that particular image element only.

Comment: I incorporated your new edited code into my site, it worked but sometimes the image would not change, or it would go 5/6 changes without a problem and then stop. I've also checked out your jsFiddle and get the same problem. Strange :| Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have tried various ways but haven't seemed to be able to get it to work seamlessly. I have it working now but it's total overkill I expect for what I actually need.

So the following code picks a random image on page load using PHP and then jQuery/Javascript/CSS to randomly display another image at 5s intervals and all images can be linked etc.

PHP -

```
<?php

$img_rand = array(
   1 => array(
         'url' => 'www.tautic.com/', 
        'img' => '1.jpg', 
        'wth' => '472',        
        'hgt' => '100',      
      'ttl' => 'Tautic',    
        'alt' => 'Tautic'  
),                              
   2 => array(
         'url' => 'www.designspark.com/', 
        'img' => '2.jpg', 
        'wth' => '472',        
        'hgt' => '100',        
      'ttl' => 'Design Spark',    
        'alt' => 'Design Spark'  
),
   3 => array(
         'url' => 'www.involutionstudios.net/',
        'img' => '3.jpg',
        'wth' => '472',        
        'hgt' => '100',        
      'ttl' => 'Involution Studios - Web Design',   
        'alt' => 'Involution Studios - Web Design'  
),
   4 => array(
         'url' => 'www.explorestem.co.uk/', 
        'img' => '4.jpg', 
        'wth' => '472',     
        'hgt' => '100',        
      'ttl' => 'Explore Stem',    
        'alt' => 'Explore Stem' 

),
); 

$img = array_rand($img_rand); 
echo('

   <a href="http://'.$img_rand[$img]['url'].'" title="'.$img_rand[$img]['ttl'].'" target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/'.$img_rand[$img]['img'].'" width="'.$img_rand[$img]['wth'].'" height="'.$img_rand[$img]['hgt'].'" alt="'.$img_rand[$img]['alt'].'" /> 
   </a>

');

?>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">



function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');


     var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
     var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
     var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="random-img">
<div id="slideshow"> 



    <div class="active">
    <?php require($INC_DIR. "rah.php");?>
    </div>
    <div>
   <a href="http://www.tautic.com/" title="Tautic" target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/1.jpg" width="472" height="100" alt="Tautic" /> 
   </a>

    </div>
    <div>
   <a href="http://www.designspark.com/" title="Design Spark" target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/2.jpg" width="472" height="100" alt="Design Spark" /> 
   </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="http://www.involutionstudios.net/" title="Involution Studios - Web Design" target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/3.jpg" width="472" height="100" alt="Involution Studios - Web Design" /> 
   </a>

    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="http://www.explorestem.co.uk/" title="Explore Stem" target="_blank">
    <img src="sponsorimg/4.jpg" width="472" height="100" alt="Explore Stem" /> 
   </a>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And finally CSS

```
.random-img 
{
position: fixed ;
bottom:15px;
z-index:20;
width:470px;
height:100px;
right:2%;
overflow:hidden;
border:5px solid white;
border-radius:10px;


}


#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow DIV {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow DIV.active {
    z-index:30;
}

#slideshow DIV.last-active {
    z-index:25;
}
```

If anyone has a better way to display a random image on page load with a unique link and change to a random image at a certain time interval, please let me know :) I would love to minimise it all.

Thanks